# How to set a variable in a Makefile to a filename via a file pattern, only if the pattern has ONE match

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, filepattern

I have a makefile for GNU make to build documents from markdown text files. The makefile has a variable `INPUT` I want to set to the filename of the markdown file. All markdown files follow the pattern *.md.

However I want set `INPUT` only to the filename when there is only **one** file matching the pattern, if there are more than one markdown file, make should exit with an error.

I tried the obvious choice

```
INPUT ?= *.md
```

but this sets INPUT of course to a list of **all* matches. So it works correctly for a directory which contains, say, only `file_a.md`, but in a directory with

```
file_a.md
file_b.md
```

`INPUT` contains afterwards "`file_a.md file_b.md`", which messes up my rules expecting INPUT to contain **one** file or to exit.

Any way to assign `INPUT` as I want to with makefile syntax?

Comment: What do you want to be assigned to `INPUT` if there is more than one file? Nothing? Do you want make to throw an error?

Comment: Yes, If there is more than one match I want `make` to exit with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you need to use the `$(wildcard)` function to force the globbing to be done immediately (otherwise make will wait until the variable is used in an appropriate place before expanding the glob).

```
INPUT ?= $(wildcard *.md)

ifneq (1,$(words $(INPUT)))
    $(error Too many or two few input files found.)
endif
```

Comment: Great idea to use the `wildcard` function. That's what I was missing. Thx!